# SQL Update list of records coming from select

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a list of records coming from a `SELECT` statement I'm trying with something of this kind but I got errors regarding the statement format:

```
UPDATE
noleggio_veicoli
SET
data_esportazione = CURDATE()
WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM noleggio_veicoli WHERE id_convenzionato = 3);
```

But it just returns:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'noleggio_veicoli'
>   for update in FROM clause

It looks like **MySQL** is only able to run classic `UPDATE` i.e.:

```
UPDATE
    noleggio_veicoli
SET 
    data_esportazione = CURDATE()
WHERE
    id_convenzionato = 3;
```

Unlucky this's not what I need since `SELECT` query I need to chain to the `UPDATE` statement is more complex and depends on *Views* already defined in the SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Maxim said, you should do something like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS (
  SELECT id FROM noleggio_veicoli where id_convenzionato=3
);

update noleggio_veicoli set data_esportazione=curdate() 
where id in (select id from temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update data that match a `select p.id from parent p inner join child c on c.pid=p.id left  join child2 c2 on c.x=c2.y where c.xx=yy and p.x=y...` you can do something like:

```
update parent p 
  set aaa=bbbb 
  from child c 
  left join child2 c2 on c.x=c2.y
  where c.pid=p.id and c.xx=yy and p.x=y ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this with a `join`:

```
UPDATE noleggio_veicoli nv JOIN
       noleggio_veicoli nv3
       ON nv.id = nv3.id and nvid3.id_convenzionato = 3
    SET data_esportazione = curdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason MySql doesn't allow to reference the same table you update in a first level subquery.

But you can work around that via a subqueryinception.  *(It's not a real word, probably)*
I.e. using a sub-query in the sub-query.

Example using an `IN`:

```
UPDATE noleggio_veicoli
SET data_esportazione = current_date
WHERE id IN (select id from (select id from noleggio_veicoli where id_convenzionato = 3) q);
```

It works also with an `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE noleggio_veicoli as t
SET data_esportazione = current_date
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    select 1 
    from (select id, id_convenzionato from noleggio_veicoli) as t2
    where t2.id_convenzionato = 2
      and t2.id = t.id
);
```

You can test it [here](http://rextester.com/IUR44867) on *rextester*

Answer (score -1):

You can't update and read from one table at the same time. At first you must 
select necessary ids and save them to somewhere, for example to [temporary table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/)